# How can I rotate a QGIS layer with Python?

Tags: python, qgis

I want to rotate x degrees a layer in QGIS. I have read than I can use shapely library to do that. Despite of that I have installed in Python this library when I try to use it from QGIS I've got an error.

[image]

How can I add shapely to QGIS or use it from QGIS?

**Edit I:**

I have imported shapely, but now I've got another error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit II:**

I'm using Alaska sample data. How can I use a valid layer?

[image]

**Edit III:**

Maybe my error is due that my data are old?. I have downloaded a version of Alaska sample data and when I have opened the project it told me that this data are for a previous version. Could this be the reason of my error?

I have checked that iface.activeLayer() returns a QgsMapLayer who is a father class of QgsVectorLayer.

If I execute this code

```
import shapely
layer = iface.activeLayer()
print layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer
```

I've got this response:

> execfile(u'/tmp/tmpGiJxh5.py'.encode('UTF-8'))
>
> **True**

So I don't understand why I get this error:

[image]

Comment: `import shapely`? Write it on a row. If that doesnt work you need to install it.

Comment: How can I do that in QGIS?

Comment: How can I get a valid layer?

Comment: No idea... I'm just pointing out that your layer has no bounds (which apparently it needs for that function).

Comment: You may want to consider asking this on https://gis.stackexchange.com/ instead, where you will find a bunch of people with QGIS experience.